# this.props.children({extra: 'things'}) not working

Tags: reactjs

I would like to pass some state to a component's children like this (example seen [here](https://youtu.be/BcVAq3YFiuc?t=30m21s))

```
const WithExtraThings = ({ children }) => children({extra: 'things'})
```

The pattern above isn't working so I am doing this

```
const WithExtraThings = ({ children }) =>
{React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { extra: 'things' })}
```

Can you confirm that the first example is outdated ?

Comment: The first example does work, if `children` is actually a single function like in the video you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example works as long as `children` in a single function. See [Functions as Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#functions-as-children) in the reactjs docs.

It's not outdated at all, the opposite is the case. It's the new flavor of the week to replace HOC's.